# Django, how to filter for a range of rows then pick the one with max date?

Tags: django

**Goal:**

In here I am filtering for deals with the given id and from those I would like to pick the one with the latest date.

```
contact.deal_set.filter(deal_id=deal_id).aggregate(Max('deal_start_datetime'))
```

However this only gives back a dictionary with the max date in it. I need the row though.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .latest method provide for django query sets.

For example in your particular case:

contact.deal_set.filter(deal_id=deal_id).latest('deal_start_datetime')

Django Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
contact.deal_set.filter(deal_id=deal_id).order_by('-deal_start_datetime')
```

This will sort queryset by `deal_start_datetime` in reverse, 0th element is the latest one, you can get it as

```
latest_contact = contact.deal_set.filter(deal_id=deal_id).order_by('-deal_start_datetime')[0]
```